# Use PASS word as variable name in python

Tags: variables, python-3.x, dictionary, syntax-error

What i am trying to do is create a dictionary in python 3.4 that will have one key named pass. Right now when I try to do this I only get an "invalid syntax".

```
login_data = dict(email=USERNAME, lsd=LSD, login=LOGIN ,pass=PASSWORD)
```

I am new to python thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't**. [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass) is a python keyword and as such it's *not* a valid identifier.

You can append a trailing underscore to make it into a valid identifier and use `pass_` (this is the usual convention in such situations), or you can use a completely different name instead.

---

Note that `pass` is not a valid *identifier*, but you can use it as a string.
In your case you can build the dictionary using the dictionary literal:

```
login_data = {'email': USERNAME, 'lsd': LSD, 'login': LOGIN, 'pass': PASSWORD}
```